# increment begin() (of a list) in c++ stl doesn't work

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl

I have this code

```
list<int> p {5,3,6,2,1};
vector<int> v {2,3,4};
cout<<*(v.begin() + 1);
cout<<*(p.begin() +1);
```

I get output of the 3rd line as 3 but the 4th line shows this error

> no match for '`operator+`' (operand types are '`std::list<int>::iterator` {aka `std::_List_iterator<int>`}' and '`int`')

What's wrong here .. why does the increment doesn't work with a list pointer..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterators come in different forms, some more general than others.

`vector` iterators are called RandomAccess, the most general type.

`list` iterators are Bidirectional. This means that they can move forward or backwards in steps of 1, but you can't use `+` or `-` to perform multiple movements at once.

There is a standard function `std::next` that will perform multiple movements on an iterator:

```
cout << * std::next(p.begin(), 1);
```

The reason for this is that typically each entry of a `list` lives in its own piece of memory, with a pointer to the next entry of the list.   So the only way to implement a jump of multiple steps is actually to perform several steps of size one.

In theory they could have made operator `+` translate to `std::next`, even for bidirectional iterators, but they didn't.

As suggested by T.C., perhaps the rationale is that `+` on a random access iterator is an O(1) operation, but `std::next` on a bidirectional iterator is an O(n) operation , and they wanted to retain the semantic that un-overloaded `+` already had of being a constant-time operation.

Comment: `std::next` is easier in many cases. The rationale is presumably that you don't want to hide a linear-time operation behind an overloaded operator.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah I realized about `std::next` just after submitting :X

Comment: No need to pass `1` to `next` here.

Comment: @Yakk True although I wanted to illustrate that it can be used for adding other numbers